# Attempt to invoke virtual method error when i try to access data android

Tags: android

I'm a newbie in android world, when I try to get data from the database, I meet this error, bellow is my database access code

```
public static boolean Checkduplicate(String activity_name, String location, String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase dtb = ActivityHandler.db;
    String Query = "Select * from  Activity  where activity_name = " + activity_name + "and location =" + location + "and _date =" + date;
    Cursor cursor = dtb.rawQuery(Query, null);
    if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return false;
}
```

Here is the error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.vinhg.comp1661_nguyengiavinh, PID: 31092
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.vinhg.comp1661_nguyengiavinh.ActivityHandler.Checkduplicate(ActivityHandler.java:32)
                  at com.example.vinhg.comp1661_nguyengiavinh.MainActivity.addData(MainActivity.java:41)
                  at com.example.vinhg.comp1661_nguyengiavinh.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:32)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5340)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21610)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

Here is my full ActivityHandler class

```
public class ActivityHandler {
private static SQLiteDatabase db;
public  ActivityHandler(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler dbDatabaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    this.db = dbDatabaseHandler.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    try{
        db.close();
    }catch (Exception ex){

    }
    super.finalize();
}

public static boolean Checkduplicate(String activity_name, String location, String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase dtb = ActivityHandler.db;
    String Query = "Select * from  Activity  where activity_name = " + activity_name + "and location =" + location + "and _date =" + date;
    Cursor cursor = dtb.rawQuery(Query, null);
    if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: i already read that topic but can't find the solution for my case

Comment: I suck at java, but it seems that `dtb` is `null`, probably because `ActivityHandler.db` is `null` as well. The duplicate applies. Just read the error message.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I suck at java too, but if dtb was null, would that not be revealed immediately by a debugger inspection after a break on the 'dtb.rawQuery' line?

Comment: the line you're mentionning is the one causing the error. Calling method on a null object.

Comment: your sucking at java is bigger than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what does `static` mean and how Java Garbage Collector works.
You are assigning value to `static` property in object constructor. It means 2 things: 
1) You need to create an object of ActivityHandler first. It will initialize property `db` with value. 
2) You will need to keep reference to this object somewhere. If you will not keep the reference, object will be garbage collected which will call `finalize()` and close db. 

I'd suggest following: 
1) Remove keyword `static`, and pass an object of ActivityHandler to the method 
2) Read carefully some basic Java books like Core Java, Effective Java etc.

Comment: but if i remove the static keyword, i can't call the method in another class

Comment: Yes you can. You've got to create a new instance of ActivityHandler and then called Checkduplicate from this instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove static and write this =>

```
public class ActivityHandler {
private SQLiteDatabase db;
public ActivityHandler(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler dbDatabaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    this.db = dbDatabaseHandler.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    try{
        db.close();
    }catch (Exception ex){

    }
    super.finalize();
}

public boolean Checkduplicate(String activity_name, String location, String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase dtb = ActivityHandler.db;
    String Query = "Select * from  Activity  where activity_name = " + activity_name + "and location =" + location + "and _date =" + date;
    Cursor cursor = dtb.rawQuery(Query, null);
    if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return false;
}
```

And then in another class you create a new instance and call you method.

```
ActivityHandler activityHandler = new ActivityHandler(context);
boolean isDuplicate = activityHandler.Checkduplicate(activity_name,location, date);
```